# Other possible expressions like #frame

Tags: python, drivers

I have learned a few minutes ago that you can type # into a numbutton to create a driver. So far the only value I know is frame. While this works nicely, it's still a bit limiting. What are the other possibilities I can input to create a driver on the fly which is a great feature btw?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`frame` is currently the only updated value in the driver namespace. The rest are functions, available for use in scripted expression driver through [`bpy.app.driver_namespace`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.app.html#bpy.app.driver_namespace).

Several modules are already pre-imported to the driver namespace, like [`builtins`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html), `bpy`, [`math`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html), and [`mathutils.noise`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/mathutils.noise.html). So, other than `frame`, and unlike manually-registered functions, functions from these modules are available to scripted expression by default.

Comment: Can we get more examples? #noise.random() is an option. I suspect other noise types might work if they return a float number value instead of a vector (x, y, z) value. docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.noise.html