# What is this noisy shadow overlay that stays with the camera?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I created a scene in which the camera goes towards a cylinder with a rock texture on the inside. But from whatever angle I play it, there is this weird noise, but unlike regular noise, it stays the exact same and follows the camera.

It is like there is a picture on the camera that has an Overlay like blending mode and just shows between the camera and the texture. Does anybody have an Idea where this texture may be coming from? Here is [sample of it on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bMibsGkzrI).

Answer (score 14):

That looks to me like "regular noise" (I assume by regular noise you mean noise caused by an insufficient number of samples in cycles).

By default cycles uses a consistent pattern for sampling, and so the pattern of noise will stay the same, producing an effect like this:

[image]

*On the dark side the noise is more chaotic, but on the illuminated side of Suzanne's face you should see that the noise pattern remains mostly the same across frames*.

To fix this, change the *Seed* of the noise pattern so that it's different every frame (or every few frames), and/or increase then number of samples. To do this, type `#frame` into the *Seed* setting in *Render settings > Sampling*:

[image]

This will create a [*driver*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Basics/Drivers) which will set the *Seed* based on the expression typed into the field, [where `#frame` is equal to the frame number](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2893/599).

*Note that you may have to allow the driver and reload your .blend (save before reloading!) in order for the driver to work. See [After updating to Blender 2.68 Driver Scripts are no longer automatically excecuted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1903/599) for details.*

Optionally add some math to the expression, e.g. `#frame/10` to change the seed only on every tenth frame.

This will break up this noise and make all the noise chaotic, which makes the noise less likely to be preserved by lossily compressed video formats.

[image]

*Click the image above to see a compressed video version.*

**On more recent versions of blender** there is a button to change the Seed automatically:

[image]

The small clock icon highlighted in yellow here, when pressed will automatically adjust the seed each frame.