# Texture appears to stand still when the camera is animated

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing

I’m modeling an address book and have a mesh with tabs (UV mapped). I’ve created one .png with a paper surface image and the letters of the alphabet in black. Animated a slow camera pan. After rendering a targa sequence the texture appears in place but there seems to be another texture or layer or grain that doesn't move. Its mostly noticeable around the black fonts but once you see whats going on its everywhere. Almost as if there is a slight transparency.

Blender 2.76 / Cycles

Link to project file and short .mov
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/34y1weq6raspbzg/AAA_lJp4Mw_lvHwdo_DXkKiya?dl=0

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this noisy shadow overlay that stays with the camera?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19659/what-is-this-noisy-shadow-overlay-that-stays-with-the-camera) adn http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/925/can-you-change-the-render-seed-for-each-frame-of-an-animation-in-cycles/926#926

Answer (score 3):

That texture that doesn't move is caused by having the same seed for noise on every frame, so the final render has a fixed noise pattern.

You need to animate the noise seed. Use the Clock-like icon on the sampling settings and render again,

[image]

Comment: Thank you cegaton! That solved my problem. I also increased my samples to get rid of any remaining "fixed" noise.